# How to use lookup_table to color tensor data in paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have the following input VTK file. I would like to display each tensor defined in this file as a tensor glyph with the color defined in the lookup table from the same file. How can I do it in paraview? Currently, I load the file into paraview and add "Tensor Glyph" as a filter, but the ellipses are colored in blue, red, white and pink color. I would like them to be colored in red, green, blue and yellow as defined in the lookup table.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Random data to test tensors
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 4 float
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 0

POINT_DATA 4

TENSORS spherical_ellipsoid float
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

SCALARS sample_scalars float
LOOKUP_TABLE rgbtable
0 1 2 3 
METADATA
INFORMATION 0

LOOKUP_TABLE rgbtable 4
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

ParaView ignores the .vtk defined lookuptable. you have to define the lookuptable in ParaView manually.